# Label observations by order of input in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a dataset of 60 observations and I'm trying to create a new variable to label the first 30 observations as "A" and the second 30 observations as "B". I assume I would need to use an IF THEN statement for this, but how would I go about creating the new variable and writing the statement to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out a roundabout way to solve this.

```
DATA market_new;
SET mydata_old;
  id = _N_;  
RUN;
```

Then using conditional logic within this.

```
IF id <31 THEN Letter = 'A';
IF id >=31 THEN Letter = 'B';
```

Comment: That's not a roundabout way to solve it.  That is the way to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

The `_N_` internal variable is what you want to use.  I would first permanently capture this in a variable, like `row_num=_N_`, because if the data set gets reordered for some reason, `_N_` will change.  Then you can do your conditional assignments according to the value of row_num.